# Looking for a sequence number in a series of char* buffers?

Tags: c++, c, gdb

I am receiving a stream of const char* msg types of a certain size_t len. At some byte offset within there there is a sequence number (32 or 64 byte, im not sure which) so my idea was to do the following every time I get one of the msg things:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
{
    uint32_t seq = *(uint32_t*) msg[i];
    cout << "seq" << i << " " << seq << endl;
}
//and similar for 64 bytes
```

so that afterwards I can group the lines with the same offset and see which offset `i` is giving me sequential looking output. The problem with this is that I segfault with stuff like:

```
(gdb) p *(uint32_t*) msg[i]
Cannot access memory at address 0x2d
```

How can I carry out my little search idea for the sequence numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
uint32_t seq = *(uint32_t*) &msg[i];
```

and

```
(gdb) p *(uint32_t*)&msg[i]
```

---

**EDIT**: A bigger change, which is potentially more portable is:

```
uint32_t seq;
memcpy(&seq, msg + i, sizeof(seq));
seq = ntohl(seq);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char msg[30];
for ( int i = 0; i < 30; i++ )
    msg[i] = '\0';

char *iter_p = NULL;
iter_p = msg;

int i = 0;
while ( iter_p < &msg[30] ) {

    uint32_t seq = *(uint32_t *)iter_p;
    cout << "seq" << i << "  " << seq << endl;
    iter_p += 4;
    i++;
}
```

Try iterating through like this, step an iterator pointer through. =)

iter_p +=4 --> step 32 bits, since iter_p is a character.

Answer (score 0):

that's not how you convert bytes to an int, you are trying to dereference a pointer to a location in memory that doesn't exist.  Try something like this: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/3076/

Comment: I didn't include the endianness just for clarity (i do ntoh things). I had forgotten the &.

Answer (score 0):

You make a simple mistake: msg[i] return the VALUE of the char at position i. To get the address of it you should use msg + i or &msg[i].
But this code is not portable for some architectures that can't read unaligned word.

The best way of reading the unaligned word is using the packed structures:

```
#pragma pack(1)
struct Header {
   uint32_t seq;
};
#pragma pack()

for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
{
    const Header *h = (const Header *)(msg + i);
    cout << "seq" << i << " " << htonl(h->seq) << endl;
}
```

Pay attention for the endian issue and htonl call.